# #hashtag navigation glitch on chrome - jumps to some sections correctly, but not to all

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am bashing my head trying to find the root cause of the following glitch:

[http://apapartnership.com/vol3](http://apapartnership.com/volume-3/)

Going to vol2 or vol3 and clicking any of the #hash links on the table of contents produces odd results:

1.- If I click any 'chapter' link from 1 to 16-18 (up to the point before you need to scroll to see the rest of the table of contents) - everything is seemingly working just fine. You get taken to the indicated section.

2.- If I click any chapter link near the 'border' or threshold between the first 16-18 items and the next few that require me to scroll down on the table of contents - there will be movement - but not to the right section.

3.- Sometimes, if I click everything several times, it will then start working properly.

4.- This glitch is not reproduce-able in vol1. Unlike the other two volumes, the table of contents is not big enough to warrant the overflow but, even then, this may very well have nothing to do with it.

**NEW EDIT: It is reproduce-able in vol1 if I make the window height narrow enough to force the scrolling to become active for the table of contents.**

My first reaction was to test this on firefox and, to my surprise, it works just fine there. It is only with chrome - 48.0.25 (as of the time of this writing) that I see this glitch happening.

I suspect it has something to do with the very lengthy one-page document and the time it takes for it all to load - but... I can't know for sure. Maybe its a conflict with some of the jquery code being fired?

As usual, any help or pointers in the right direction are more than welcome.

Cheers
Sotkra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is not the execution, but the planning. Your problem appears to root in loading too much content, at least compared to the average internet page.

Browsers nowadays are no longer streamlined for loading large amounts of data (that's what we use powerful servers for, right?), but for heavily animated pages (all the animations should run smoothly without hiccups in movement continuity - that's what every browser manufacturer and/or framework developer aims for - the ultimate smooth animation awe[someness]).

You should only load a single section and the table of contents at one time. To me it looks like the perfect AngularJs use case, which would call a REST API asynchronously to get each section's content while keeping the summary.

The proper/actual answer to your question probably originates in a `markup` error or something similar. But that's another huge problem you are facing. As it is, your project is **almost impossible to develop, maintain and debug**.

Even though it doesn't directly answer your question, I think my suggestion addresses your real problem better than any `on-topic` answer could.

---

EDIT: (from comments) Apparently, placing the `position:fixed` navigation menu directly under the `<body>` fixes the problem. My advice in this case is to completely remove the `#toc` element from the post content and place it under the `<body>` using this small script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('#toc').appendTo('body');
});
```

Of course, it requires some changes to a few selectors in your CSS, so the styles apply to the moved item.

Comment: I agree on some of your points. However, the client is applying changes and fixes to the document and he specifically requested a huge single page as a comfortable preview method. The images won't make it to the final version - even when heavily compressed they are still 60+ MB just for vol1 alone. Having said that, If I remove ALL IMAGES and slim down the page to less than 1MB of total filesize, the glitch persists.

Comment: I also tried deleting 99% of the html content and the glitch persists. As soon as I delete a few items on the table of contents itself, the glitch disappears. This means that the glitch has more to do with having that 2ndary scrollbar on the fixed table-of-contents div than the size of the document or the content inside it. So I am very keen on finding out the root cause of the issue.

Comment: I believe the key to debugging this is the M in [mcve]. Perhaps try to create a long summary but have only placeholders (instead of actual section content)? Also try to temporarily change the positioning of the summary? Why does the summary toggle when you go to a section? `console.log` is clearly your friend on this one.

Comment: Andrei: I went for precisely that: I limited my content and the bug persisted. The only thing that makes any difference is whether my table of contents div with my #hash links is on a fixed div with scrolling of its own or if its a position:static div using the 'general' scrolling of the rest of the page. This doesn't happen on firefox. It's certainly an IE bug. I solved it partially by toggling between positon:fixed and static depending on whether the table of contents is 'open for use' or collapsed to make more room for text. Really really odd =/

Comment: To clarify further: if the table of contents div, with positon:fixed needs scrolling because its taller than the height of your window, those links near the edge, or beyond the edge (requiring you to scroll down before you can access and click them) are the ones that cease to work. Again, this is just on chrome.

Comment: All I can think of is add a function to `console.log` the entire event on any `click` on menu. Check if `event.target` is correct. This will tell you if the scrolling function is the problem or the `click` is actually registered on another button, due to some odd positioning bug on the menu. Since your menu is fixed, you might want to place it as a direct child of the `<body>` (if it's not already)?

Comment: I (manually) moved the menu (toc) under `<body>` (made it `position:fixed; height: 100vw; oveflow-y:auto;`) and it started working properly. Of course, there are some styling issues to handle but I trust you can easily fix those, looking at your CSS score... !?

Comment: Andrei: thank you for that find. I was unaware that the fixed div had to be placed right after <body> otherwise the scroll overflow could cause it to glitch. Because I am using wordpress, I will keep alternating between position static and fixed - because I can only add this manually inputed table of contents within .entry content as per wordpress's 'way' rather than before <body> without making it harder for the non-tech saavy client. Should I find myself coding this from scratch - or on a larger scope project, I will remind myself to do as you suggested. Thanks for helping me understand =)

Comment: Please modify your answer and add the comment with the actual core answer so that this might be of use to anyone else bumping into this specific glitch/issue. Cheers.

Comment: I believe keeping the element inside `.post-entry` will lead to more problems on different devices/browsers than just moving it outside on page load. I updated the answer with how I'd try to solve this.